# CRL number generation sequence

Tags: certificate, x509, pki

RFC 5280 states that the CRL number should be monotonically increase. I have seen this common practice of incrementing the CRL number by 1, everytime a new CRL is generated. But can i use epoch time stamp as the CRL number, which is monotonically increasing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can use any algorithm as long as it conforms RFC requirements. However, sequential increment provides an ability to track the history of CRL updates.

Comment: I did think about tracking the CRL, but I felt UNIX timestamp is even simpler compared to sequential increment, agree ?

Comment: I personally don't think that it is simpler, but it is acceptable.